# Opening a file from a Qt String

Tags: c++, file-io, qt4, qstring, qfiledialog

I am making a Qt application and I have a button to open a file, which is connected to a custom slot. This is the slot code so far:

```
void MainWindow::file_dialog() {
    const QFileDialog *fd;
    const QString filename = fd->getOpenFileName();
}
```

How could I have it then convert the file name to a `const char *`, open the file, read it and store the text in a QString, and then close the file. I am using Qt4.

Answer (score 8):

To read the contents of a file, you can do [this](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qfile.html#open-4):

```
QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName();

QFile file(filename);
 if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
     return;

QString content = file.readAll();

file.close();
```